# Pandas GroupBy and max on MultiIndex upper column level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, multi-index

I'm trying to get the max of 2 columns for each row in a Pandas Multi-Column Index Dataframe.

I've loaded multiple stock data into Pandas and I am trying to get the max of the Close and Open price for each stock and each day.

The example I've given is a simplistic example of what I am really trying to do, so I'd appreciate it if someone can give me a solution that doesn't require to loop through each column or row and has a quick run time.

```
# import libaries
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf

#declare dates
end_date = datetime.date.today()
start_date = end_date - relativedelta(days=3)

#load stock data (this code sometimes brings an error, just rerun it and it should work within a few tries)
yf.pdr_override()
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(['AAPL','FB'], start_date, end_date)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
              Open               Close  
              AAPL     FB        AAPL     FB
Date
2019-05-29    176.42   183.50    177.38   182.19
2019-05-30    177.95   183.08    178.30   183.01
2019-05-31    176.23   180.28    175.07   177.47
```

Desired Output:

```
              Open               Close              Max     
              AAPL     FB        AAPL     FB        AAPL     FB
Date
2019-05-29    176.42   183.50    177.38   182.19    177.38   183.50
2019-05-30    177.95   183.08    178.30   183.01    178.30   183.08
2019-05-31    176.23   180.28    175.07   177.47    176.23   180.28
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution IMO is using `groupby` with the `level` argument along the columns:

```
u = df.groupby(level=1, axis=1).max()
```

Or, more specifically,

```
u = df[['Open','Close']].groupby(level=1, axis=1).max()
u
              AAPL      FB
Date                      
2019-05-29  177.38  183.50
2019-05-30  178.30  183.08
2019-05-31  176.23  180.28
```

Now, fix the columns and concatenate the result.

```
u.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Max'], u.columns])
pd.concat([df, u], axis=1)

              Open           Close             Max        
              AAPL      FB    AAPL      FB    AAPL      FB
Date                                                      
2019-05-29  176.42  183.50  177.38  182.19  177.38  183.50
2019-05-30  177.95  183.08  178.30  183.01  178.30  183.08
2019-05-31  176.23  180.28  175.07  177.47  176.23  180.28
```

Comment: Thanks cs95! I knew I had to use groupby, just didn't know what arguments to use. Anyways this is what I was looking for except I had more columns like 'Volume' and I only wanted to get the max of 'Open' and 'Close'. I should've been more clearer, but I got the answer, here it is in case anyone else needs it: df[['Open','Close']].groupby(level=1, axis=1).max()

Answer (score 0):

Just try using this

Compare two or more columns in a dataframe using max keyword.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [-2, 8, 1], "C": [1, 2, 3], "D": [-2, 8, 1]})
df["E"] = df[["A", "B"]].max(axis=1)
df["F"] = df[["C", "D"]].max(axis=1)
print(df)

Output:

    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   1   -2  1   -2  1   1
1   2   8   2   8   8   8
2   3   1   3   1   3   3
```